# Combining two lambdas in C++

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm trying to write come code as follows. The aim is to provide a lambda function to be used elsewhere that converts position to velocity based on some user configurations.

```
base_vel = [=] (myVectorClass position) { return myVectorClass(0.0, 0.0); };
rand_vel = [=] (myVectorClass position) { return myVectorClass(0.0, 0.0); };

if (base_vel_type == vel_type::TYPE_1) {
   base_vel = [=](myVectorClass position)
   {   // code that finds velocity as a function of position
       return myVectorClass(x, y); };
}

// more types

if (add_random == true);
   rand_vel = [=](myVectorClass position)
   {   // code that finds a random component to velocity
       return myVectorClass(x, y); };
}

return base_vel + rand_vel;
```

Something isn't working correctly. I suspect that either the code inside the if statements is not overriding the previously declared lambda, or that my addition of the two lambdas at the end is not working as expected. How are lambda functions like this supposed to be amalgamated?

Thank you for any comments.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. This isn't the actual code though, just the shortest pseudocode I could write to illustrate the question, so it's not that typo causing the problem.

Comment: You want to compose the two lambdas or to add the result of the call to the two lambdas?

Comment: The rest of the program is expecting a single lambda function out of this, not the result of the evaluation of the function, which would be of type myVectorClass. It needs the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want **appears** to be:

```
return [=](myVectorClass position) { return base_vel(position) + rand_vel(position); };
```

As per @40two's suggestion: lambdas cannot be assigned and the OP would need to define `base_vel` and `rand_vel` (and the return of the mentioned but unnamed function) as

```
std::function<myVectorClass(myVectorClass)> base_rel = //...
std::function<myVectorClass(myVectorClass)> rand_vel = //...
std::function<myVectorClass(myVectorClass)> blah_blah_blah() {
   //...
}
```

for those `if` statements to work :D